# Using a loop to replace elements of an array with the sum of the columns in another array

Tags: matlab

I have a problem where i have to generate a random 10x20 array and then get the averages of the elements in each column and then place them in a new array. So far I have the core of the program down but I can't seem to get the conditions for the while loop right.

```
A = rand(10, 20)*100; 
A = floor(A);

B = zeros(1, 20);

while A <= A(:,20)
 i = 1;
 k = 1;

 B(:,k) = floor(sum(A(:,i))/10);

 k = k + 1;
 i = i + 1;
end
```

It ends up in an infinite loop and I can't really figure out why.

Comment: `A=randi(100,10,20)-1` is another way to get your initial `A` matrix. Then `mean(A)` will give you a vector of the mean of each column of `A`. Your while loop will never end because `A` doesn't change at each iteration so if `A<=A(:,20)` is true once, it will always be true. I don;t actually understand why this code works as surely `A<=A(:,20)` gives you an error?

Comment: I agree with @David. It doesn't seem as though you even ran this code, because `A <= A(:,20)` causes an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to avoid loops if you can. 
And in this case we can avoid it using build-in function (thanks to @David )

```
A = rand(10, 20)*100;
B = mean(A);
```

P.S. About using `randi` and `rand` - the main difference is `randi` generates `integer` and `rand` - `doubles`. So it depends of what you need.